# Sandbox paypal recurring amount not credited to business account

Tags: paypal, e-commerce, paypal-sandbox, paypal-subscriptions

I am having strange issue I am using Express checkout method and API SDK to create recurring profile.

Everything was working fine till 16 August.

After 16 August not sure why i am not receiving amount in seller business account for recurring profile
I have created lot of profiles for 2 days recurring payment to test application.

Any idea why amount not debitted from buyer and credited to seller sandbox account?
I have also check IPN history they have not sending any IPN

I am using .NET platform.

Thanks,
Jigar Joshi

Comment: I'm having a similar issue in PHP, I'm not getting initial amount for recurring payments, while the recurring profile start date is next month. Hope to get some help

Comment: Yes i am not able to received initial amount as well as recurring payment it was working before 2 days.

Comment: @andrew-angell,  If you could please help us in this regard

Comment: I am Getting same issue. My recurring payments was working till yesterday. But it suddenly stopped.